# Unable to read .rtf file in VS.NET 2008 Setup

Tags: .net, installation, setup-deployment

I have created a simple windows application in .NET 2008.
Im packaging the same into a setup file using .NET Setup and Deployment.
Also i am customizing it to include a License Agreement UI.
And  i am pointing the License Agreement window to read the license.rtf file which is being included in the Application folder.

After successful build, if i run the setup file i can see the License Agreement window but i cannot see the content of my file.

Any ideas what is the issue behind this ?

Regards
CL

Comment: Reasons can be many. How does the license agrement reader read the file?

Answer (score 0):

The License file property is set to the file, which is present in my Application folder.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by myself...
The issue was .NET Setup and Deployment only reads the .rtf file created using wordpad.
It does not read the doc files or txt files renamed to .rtf ...

So the solution is to use the .rtf files only